Why is floor division inconsistent with division follow by floor, e.g. 1//0.2 = 4.0
The operator // for integer division is called "floor division" in the python documentation, but comparing to other floor implementations there is a discrepancy, for example:
>>> numpy.floor(1/0.2)
5.0
>>> float(math.floor(1/0.2))
5.0
>>> 1//0.2
4.0

Quite unexpected. Investigating a little further we can see that
>>> numpy.floor(1/0.20000000000000001)
5.0
>>> numpy.floor(1/0.2000000000000001)
4.0

while
>>> 1//0.19999999999999999
5.0
>>> 1//0.199999999999999999
4.0

It's standard CPython from anaconda. Maybe it could be an implementation detail like doing if a<b vs if not a>b, which wouldn't matter much for floats, but when the focus is integers, it makes a difference.
What's the reason for this discrepancy, and isn't it at least close to being a bug?

"but when the focus is integers, it makes a difference" - you might be focusing on the integers here, but you're using floats. 0.2 isn't one fifth.

0.2 is not exactly the rational number 1/5, so 1/0.2 is not exactly 5, but rather a number ever so slightly less than 5. Look at decimal.Decimal(.2).as_integer_ratio(), for example.

Yes, I'm fine with these things, but then why is the result different for floor()? And whatever the answer is (maybe there's a tolerance in the floor() functions), why isn't there the same tolerance in //?

Hm, the documentation says that "The floor division and modulo operators are connected by the following identity: x == (x//y)*y + (x%y)". Maybe this prevents the floor in // from having such a tolerance.

CPython computes the floating-point remainder using fmod, and derives flooring division from that: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b80a5b20f31a067bd1c374295608df5f1210f49/Objects/floatobject.c#L661-L697.

Computers have built-in integer division instructions, so when you write 1 // 10 it never converts to floating point. The float conversion is where errors get introduced.
